# UIAlertView with textField

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

I experiment at the moment with some alertViews. Now try to set an AlertView with two textField`s. When I click "done" it should show a Log.

At the moment, the code looks like that:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Titel" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
```

The TextField should have placeholder. How do I set it up?

Comment: Look at the docs for `UIAlertView`. Use the provided methods to set it up to have a text field and to access the text field.

Comment: I found something like: alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
And it works. But how can I add a second one?

Comment: Look at the other styles.

Comment: "UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput" will with "[[alert textFieldAtIndex:1] setSecureTextEntry:NO];" work for me. Thanks

Comment: @Nanog000 If my answer worked for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: it should work:

```
 UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your_Title" message:@"Your_message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[av setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];

// Alert style customization 
[[av textFieldAtIndex:1] setSecureTextEntry:NO];
[[av textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:@"First_Placeholder"];
[[av textFieldAtIndex:1] setPlaceholder:@"Second_Placeholder"];
[av show];
```

You can access the values of the text fields on the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` of `UIAlertViewDelegate`.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
     NSLog(@"1 %@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text);
     NSLog(@"2 %@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text);
}
```